# MySQL query optimization hint needed

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, explain

could you please help me with a monster.

Do you see any issue with this one?

Would like to reach the  execution time below the second, is it possible?

Please ask for any other data you may need to understand the structure of DB. Any tips&tricks are welcome!

```
SELECT 
    ORD_CLI.COD_AGE,
    ORD_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_ID,
    OFF_CLI.off_cli_id,
    ORD_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID,
    ORD_CLI_RIGHE.COD_ART,
    ART_PESO.PESO_ART,
    ORD_CLI.ANNO_DOC,
    ORD_CLI.NUM_DOC,
    ORD_CLI.SERIE_DOC,
    ORD_CLI.DATA_DOC,
    CF.RAG_SOC_CF,
    AGENTI.NOME_AGE,
    ORD_CLI.COD_CF,
    ORD_CLI.COD_IVA,
    ORD_CLI.COD_DEP,
    ORD_CLI_TOT.IMPONIBILE_V1 AS IMPONIBILE_ORDINE,
    FATT_CLI_TOT.IMPONIBILE_V1 AS IMPONIBILE_FATTURA,
    ORD_CLI_TOT.IVA_V1,
    SUM(ART_PESO.PESO_ART) AS weight,
    SUM(FATT_CLI_RIGHE.QUANT_RIGA) AS quantity,
    SUM(FATT_CLI_RIGHE.QUANT_RIGA*FATT_CLI_RIGHE.PREZZO_LORDO_VU1) AS sell_price,
    SUM(FATT_CLI_RIGHE.QUANT_RIGA*DDT_FOR_RIGHE.PREZZO_LORDO_VU1) AS acqisition_price1,
    SUM(FATT_CLI_RIGHE.QUANT_RIGA*FATT_FOR_RIGHE.PREZZO_LORDO_VU1) AS acqisition_price2,
    SUM(FATT_CLI_RIGHE.QUANT_RIGA*FATT_CLI_RIGHE_PROVV.IMPORTO_PROVV_VU1) AS agent_reward,
    SUM(FATT_CLI_RIGHE.QUANT_RIGA*ART_PESO.PESO_ART * 0.13) AS transport_price,
    SUM(FATT_CLI_RIGHE.QUANT_RIGA*(
          FATT_CLI_RIGHE.PREZZO_LORDO_VU1 
        - COALESCE(DDT_FOR_RIGHE.PREZZO_LORDO_VU1, 0)
        - COALESCE(FATT_FOR_RIGHE.PREZZO_LORDO_VU1, 0)
        - COALESCE(FATT_CLI_RIGHE_PROVV.IMPORTO_PROVV_VU1, 0)
        - COALESCE(ART_PESO.PESO_ART, 0) * 0.13
    )) AS net_earning,
    OFF_CLI.stima_prezzo_acquisto,
    OFF_CLI.stima_prezzo_trasporto,
    OFF_CLI.stima_provvigioni_agenti,
    OFF_CLI.stima_utile

FROM ORD_CLI 

INNER JOIN ORD_CLI_RIGHE         
    ON ORD_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_ID = ORD_CLI.DOC_ID 

LEFT JOIN ORD_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC   
    ON ORD_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID = ORD_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.DOC_RIGA_ID

INNER JOIN ART_PESO 
    ON ART_PESO.COD_ART = ORD_CLI_RIGHE.COD_ART

INNER JOIN ORD_CLI_TOT 
    ON ORD_CLI.DOC_ID = ORD_CLI_TOT.DOC_ID

INNER JOIN AGENTI 
    ON AGENTI.COD_AGE = ORD_CLI.COD_AGE

INNER JOIN CF 
    ON CF.COD_CF = ORD_CLI.COD_CF

LEFT JOIN FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC   
    ON ORD_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID = FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.ORD_RIGA_ID

LEFT JOIN FATT_CLI_RIGHE        
    ON FATT_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID = FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.DOC_RIGA_ID

LEFT JOIN FATT_CLI_TOT
    ON FATT_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_ID = FATT_CLI_TOT.DOC_ID

LEFT JOIN FATT_CLI_RIGHE_PROVV 
    ON FATT_CLI_RIGHE_PROVV.DOC_RIGA_ID = FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.DOC_RIGA_ID

LEFT JOIN FATT_CLI_RIGHE_LOTTI 
    ON FATT_CLI_RIGHE_LOTTI.DOC_RIGA_ID = FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.DOC_RIGA_ID

LEFT JOIN  DDT_FOR_RIGHE_LOTTI  
    ON DDT_FOR_RIGHE_LOTTI.COD_LOT = FATT_CLI_RIGHE_LOTTI.COD_LOT

LEFT JOIN  DDT_FOR_RIGHE         
    ON DDT_FOR_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID = DDT_FOR_RIGHE_LOTTI.DOC_RIGA_ID

LEFT JOIN FATT_FOR_RIGHE         
    ON FATT_FOR_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID = FATT_CLI_RIGHE_LOTTI.COD_LOT

LEFT JOIN OFF_CLI_RIGHE
    ON OFF_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID = ORD_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.OFF_RIGA_ID

LEFT JOIN OFF_CLI
    ON OFF_CLI.DOC_ID = OFF_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_ID

WHERE 
    ORD_CLI.COD_BUSN_UN='P' 
AND OFF_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID IS NOT NULL

AND ORD_CLI.DATA_DOC >= '2012-11-29'
AND ORD_CLI.DATA_DOC <= '2013-02-28'   
GROUP BY ORD_CLI.DOC_ID 
ORDER BY   ORD_CLI.DATA_DOC 
DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Time of execution

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 30 total, Query took 6.3458 sec)
```

EXPLAIN of the query

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type   | possible_keys                                                               | key                              | key_len | ref                                        | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ORD_CLI              | range  | PRIMARY,ORD_CLI_DATA_DOC,ORD_CLI_COD_CF,ORD_CLI_COD_BUSN_UN,ORD_CLI_COD_AGE | ORD_CLI_DATA_DOC                 | 4       | NULL                            | 3728 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | AGENTI               | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY                          | 38      | ORD_CLI.COD_AGE                 |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | CF                   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY                          | 38      | ORD_CLI.COD_CF                  |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ORD_CLI_TOT          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY                          | 62      | ORD_CLI.DOC_ID                  |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ORD_CLI_RIGHE        | ref    | PRIMARY,ORD_CLI_RIGHE_DOC_ID,ORD_CLI_RIGHE_COD_ART                          | ORD_CLI_RIGHE_DOC_ID             | 62      | ORD_CLI_TOT.DOC_ID              |    2 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ART_PESO             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY                          | 92      | ORD_CLI_RIGHE.COD_ART           |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ORD_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ORD_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC_OFF_RIGA_ID                                      | PRIMARY                          | 92      | ORD_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID       |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | OFF_CLI_RIGHE        | ref    | DOC_RIGA_ID                                                                 | DOC_RIGA_ID                      | 92      | ORD_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.OFF_RIGA_ID  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | OFF_CLI              | ref    | DOC_ID                                                                      | DOC_ID                           | 63      | OFF_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_ID              |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC  | ref    | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC_ORD_RIGA_ID                                             | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC_ORD_RIGA_ID  | 93      | ORD_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID       |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY                          | 92      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.DOC_RIGA_ID |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | FATT_CLI_TOT         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY                          | 62      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_ID           |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_PROVV | ref    | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_PROVV_DOC_RIGA_ID                                            | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_PROVV_DOC_RIGA_ID | 92      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.DOC_RIGA_ID |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_LOTTI | ref    | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_LOTTI_DOC_RIGA_ID                                            | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_LOTTI_DOC_RIGA_ID | 92      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.DOC_RIGA_ID |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | DDT_FOR_RIGHE_LOTTI  | ref    | DDT_FOR_RIGHE_LOTTI_COD_LOT                                                 | DDT_FOR_RIGHE_LOTTI_COD_LOT      | 92      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_LOTTI.COD_LOT    |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | DDT_FOR_RIGHE        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY                          | 92      | DDT_FOR_RIGHE_LOTTI.DOC_RIGA_ID |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | FATT_FOR_RIGHE       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY                          | 92      | FATT_CLI_RIGHE_LOTTI.COD_LOT    |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The following is the result of `show status like 'Handler%'` excatly after the query been executed

```
Handler_commit, 2
Handler_delete, 0
Handler_discover, 0
Handler_prepare, 0
Handler_read_first, 0
Handler_read_key, 421001
Handler_read_last, 0
Handler_read_next, 240344
Handler_read_prev, 0
Handler_read_rnd, 30
Handler_read_rnd_next, 2412
Handler_rollback, 0
Handler_savepoint, 0
Handler_savepoint_rollback, 0
Handler_update, 31846
Handler_write, 2409
```

Database structure: https://gist.github.com/moiseevigor/4988fc8868f92643c9fb

**EDIT 1**

After creation of index

```
ALTER TABLE `TCross5_NP`.`ORD_CLI` 
ADD INDEX `ORD_CLI_MULTI` (`COD_BUSN_UN` ASC, `DATA_DOC` ASC, `DOC_ID` ASC) ;
```

The execution time gone down 2 times, but still hits the `ORD_CLI_MULTI` index

Comment: The join of LEFT JOIN OFF_CLI_RIGHE can be changed to an INNER JOIN (as you check for a column from that table being non null in the WHERE clause). Can you post the table declares as some of your keys used seem to be rather long when they appear to just be ID fields.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip about left join! Just in a moment I'll make an extract, it is horrible so did not put it here ;) It is automatically generated structure by OmnisStudio. And I confirm the IDs are composite.

Answer (score 1):

First, (and has helped in many other similar queries where you appear to be dealing with a lot of "lookup" secondary table references), change start of query to

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
```

Which directs the engine to run the query in the exact order you have listed.  This will prevent it from trying to use a lookup table as a primary consideration and trying to work backwords or end-around to get the data.  Sometimes  works well, other times (rarely in my experience), hinders performance.

Next, since you are looking for an " AND OFF_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID IS NOT NULL", I would change your LEFT JOINs to INNER JOIN when joining to.

```
INNER JOIN ORD_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC   
   ON ORD_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID = ORD_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.DOC_RIGA_ID

   INNER JOIN OFF_CLI_RIGHE
      ON ORD_CLI_RIGHE_SPEC.OFF_RIGA_ID = OFF_CLI_RIGHE.DOC_RIGA_ID
```

and thus eliminate the "AND ... is not null" in the WHERE clause.

Finally, I would have an index that is multiple parts that can be optimized
FOR the query...

```
CREATE index MultipleParts on ORD_CLI  ( COD_BUSN_UN, DATA_DOC, DOC_ID );
```

The multipart index will help the WHERE, GROUP BY AND ORDER BY of the query.

Comment: Thank you will try your hints and will post updates! The `STRAIGHT_JOIN` already tried and get the same results on performance.  I'm worried about `ORD_CLI_DATA_DOC` index which looks to me been overheated, what do you think? The `INNER JOIN` does not produce any difference but in any case it is more correct.

Comment: I suppose `filesort` and/or `temparary` is impossibile to eliminate? Can you tell something on this? Thank you.